# how to add mouse listener to JLabel which contain image

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I have added an image to a `Jlabel` and I want to add mouse listener to it.
I don't know to add a mouse listener to the `Jlabel` that contains the image.

So anyone who knows how to implement this please tell me.

I want to add a mousedragged listener to the `JLabel`.
When the user drags it, it should work.

```
MouseHandler mk = new MouseHandler();
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.addMouseListener(mk);
```

I have implemented a listener in the class that extends mouse adapter.

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11890169/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try :

```
     JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
     nameLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        //override the method
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
                     // to do .........................
        }
    });
```

thats the way I understand your question.

But I guess this can help you too : 
[Drag and move a picture inside a JLabel with mouseclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130257/drag-and-move-a-picture-inside-a-jlabel-with-mouseclick)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding your mouse adapter as a mouse listener (which handles click, enter, exit, pressed, released).  You want to add it as a mouse motions listener if you want to handle drag and move events.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/image.jpg"); //Path to the image  
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon); //add image to the label

label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

You can add the actions to the above methods as required.