# Swing paint delay?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jcomponent

```
public class PaintRandomly extends JFrame
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new PaintRandomly();
}
public PaintRandomly()
{
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    this.add(new DrawingPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel
{
    Point newPoint;
    ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public DrawingPanel()
    {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
                {
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
                    {
                        newPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        shapes.add(new Rectangle(newPoint.x, newPoint.y, 1, 1));
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Shape s: shapes)
        {
            g2.draw(s);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Well I tried with zero knowledge to make a brush with which I could paint, but the thing is that it does not keep up with the speed of the mouse, does it update to slow? Because if I paint faster there are just dots, and like big spaces in beetwen...

Comment: I would suggest that you investigate on methods to avoid redrawing the entire canvas on every mouse event.  JComponent.repaint() has a method that allows for drawing in a partial area: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint(long,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: `it does not keep up with the speed of the mouse,` That is correct. A MouseEvent is NOT generated for every pixel the mouse moves. You need to actually draw a line between the previous mouse event and the current mouse event to connect the points.

Comment: Basically, what you should be doing is drawing a line between the points which you capture, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886866/drawline-issues-and-buffered-image/11893204#11893204)